# Change Column Value if Value Exists In Another Column

Tags: pandas, matching

Given the following pandas `df` -

| **Holding Account** | **Account Type** | **Column A** | **Column B** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rupert 06 (23938996) | Holding Account | 1825973 | 1702598 |
| Rupert 07 (23938996) | Holding Account | 1697870 | 1825973 |
| - | - | - | - |
| Caroline 06 (0131465) | Holding Account | 11112222 | 5435450 |
| Caroline 07 (0131465) | Holding Account | 7896545 | 11112222 |

I am trying to find a way to do the following -

- Step 1 - For the entire `df`, search for instances of Column B values appearing in Column A
  (example: Column B of `Caroline 07` == Column A of `Caroline 06`)
- Step 2 - Rows that meet the above criteria should have there Column B value changed to the Column B value of the row who they matches
  (example: `Caroline 7` Column B value will change from `11112222` to `5435450`

This means the pandas `df` will now look as follows -

| **Holding Account** | **Account Type** | **Column A** | **Column B** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rupert 06 (23938996) | Holding Account | 1825973 | 1702598 |
| Rupert 07 (23938996) | Holding Account | 1697870 | **1702598** |
| - | - | - | - |
| Caroline 06 (0131465) | Holding Account | 11112222 | 5435450 |
| Caroline 07 (0131465) | Holding Account | 7896545 | **5435450** |

Does anyone have some suggestions about how I might achieve such a result?

**Useful info:**

- Dypes = `object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this:

```
import numpy as np
df['Column B'] = np.where(df['Column B'].isin(df['Column A'].values),df['Column B'].shift(),df['Column B'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! If I may ask, how would I expand this code so that the entire row who's Column B value is transposed is also deleted? To use the example I provided in my question - how would I delete `Rupert 06 (23938996)` and `Caroline 06 (0131465)` rows?

Comment: please try this after the posted code block:

`df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Column B'],keep='last')`

Comment: My dataset is 7000 rows (above was an extract) and that code block seems to delete most rows, which it shouldn't. Any idea why the 2nd code block would do that? I am only trying to remove rows who's Column B value was transposed to another row, if that makes sense

Comment: It is because your dataset is having many repeating values in column B. In that case, I recommend you to provide a reproducible subset of the dataframe here inorder to get a more precise solution